# Ошибка передачи структуры в метод

Tags: c++, boost

Есть такой класс:

```
SocketManager.h

struct Client {
    int ID;
    char DATA[1024];
    tcp::socket CLIENT_SOCKET;
};

class Manager {
public:
    void AddConnectionListener(void(*ConnectListener)(Client));
    void AddDataRecListener(void(*DataListener)(Client));
    void onDataRec(Client sender);
    void onConnect(Client connector);
    void SendDataTo(Client);
private:
    void(*ConnListener)(Client);
    void(*DataReceiveListeer)(Client);
};
```

И его реализация:

```
SocketManager.cpp


void Manager::AddConnectionListener(void(*ConnectListener)(Client)) {
    ConnListener = ConnectListener;
}

void Manager::AddDataRecListener(void(*DataListener)(Client)) {
    DataReceiveListeer = DataListener;
}

void Manager::onDataRec(Client sender) {

}
void Manager::onConnect(Client connector) {

    ConnListener(connector); // ошибка
}
```

При попытке вызова функции по её указателю возникает ошибка:

> function "Client::Client(const Client &)" (declared implicitly) cannot
>   be referenced -- it is a deleted function boost_server    D:\C++
>   Projects\boost_server\boost_server\SocketManager.cpp

Как быть? Как передать в метод структуру?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcp::socket` не получится скопировать.

Его можно либо перемещать (возможно с помощью `std::move`), либо передавать по ссылке.

Мне кажется, здесь вам нужна именно передача по ссылке: `void onDataRec(Client &sender)` и т. д.